# How to get text from dynamically created UITextField without touching or tapping the text field (disabled user interaction)?

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uitextfield

In my application I have created textfield dynamically in for loop based on server response, I designed Every row it have five textfields. Here I have multiply the textfield1 value and textfield2 value then display in textfield4 and multiply textfield1 and textfield3 then display in textfield5 so here I have disable user interaction for textfield4 and textfield5 based on placeholder text because I want to just display the values to that textfields and make non-editable fields.

Here I have attached the empty fields screenshot for this functionality:

[image]

Here I have attached the screenshot after filled some values:

[image]

Here my problem is unable to get the textfield4 and textfield5 values because of disable user interaction. If I enable user Interaction means I am able to get the both textfield values in **textFieldShouldEndEditing**.

How to get the values of textfield4 and textfield5?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the tag for `textfield` and get the `textfield` using that tag. Refer the below example code.

```
if let txtField = self.view.viewWithTag(123) as? UITextField {
    print("txtField.text")
}
```

Comment: Then how to get the "ID" for the particular textfield?

Comment: Then how to get the "ID" for the particular textfield bro?

Comment: you should set while creating UITextField

Answer (score 0):

To me the simplest solution is to have a var which you set with the calculated textfields value at the same time you set textfield4 and 5 text. If you are looking to get a notification you can add an observer for its value.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer way of doing this might be to lay everything out within a `UITableView` which is populated by a set of objects, we'll name this object `Item`. Each `Item` could have properties such as `name`, `quantity`, `squareFootPerUnit`, `estCost`, `totalSquareFoot` and `totalCost`.

I would then create a UITableViewCell with three UITextFields (`quantity`, `estCost`, `squareFootPerUnit`) which can be edited, and three labels (`name`, `totalSquareFoot` and `totalCost`). Make your `UITableViewCell` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate` to capture the inputs from the user.

In `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, populate the `UITableViewCells` with the data from your `Item` objects. Once you have captured the `quantity`, `estCost`, `squareFootPerUnit` data from the `UITextFields`, do the calculations and assign the answers to the `totalSquareFoot` and `totalCost` properties in your `Item` object and reload the table.

There are multiple ways of assigning thee calculated values to your `Item` objects. The way I usually use is a closure(Swift) / block(Objective-C) as a property on the `UITableViewCell` which I then invoke whenever the calculation has completed. Pass the calculated answers as parameters.

**UITableView Advantages**

1. No need to handle any complicated x & y co-ordinate positioning you may have if the server returns you multiple `Item` data.
2. Easier to maintain your `Item` data by using objects.
3. No need to use `tag` objects on views or keep ahold of `tag` names.